# One constructor - multiple arguments

Tags: java, dynamic, constructor

I've found a task on some Java programming competition. One must create class Sentence with only one argument 'text' and only one constructor. Here's sample test code :

```
 Sentence s1=new Sentence("only","CAT"),
      s2=new Sentence("and", 2, "mice"),
      s3=new Sentence(s1,s2,"completely","alone"),
      s4=new Sentence(s3, "on the ", new Integer(32), "th street");

 System.out.println(s1); Only cat.
 System.out.println(s2); Only cat and 2 mice.
 System.out.println(s3); Only cat and 2 mice completely alone.
 System.out.println(s4); Only cat and 2 mice completely alone on the 32th street.
```

How one contructor can serve different sets of arguments ? Is there something like dynamical constructor which recognizes sent values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make use of [varargs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

```
public class Sentence {

    public Sentence(Object... text) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Fill in the constructor logic yourself. It may however become a bit awful to determine all the types. You could make use of `Object#toString()` and let the `Sentence` class implement one as well.

Comment: I guess the types are only those supported within test code. Dunno, haven't competed in this competition :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, java 5+ support [varargs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) - you can pass mulitple arguments of the same type, like this:

```
public Constructor(Object... args){..}
public void methodName(Object... args){..}
```

Then the arguments are accessible as an array of `Object`. But that's not always a good practice. Varargs should be used only for arguments with the same logical type. For example, a list of names. If multiple arguments should be passed I'd suggest to overload constructors.

In this case the arguments are all of the same logical type - "word", so this is a nice way to do it.

Comment: Well... the various printf methods use varargs with different argument type.  I disagree with the "not good practice" remark.

Answer (score 1):

If you accept Object... value, then you can convert anything to a string with toString. toString is defined on Object so every Object should support it.

Comment: Although, not every object will provide an implementation which is practically useful to this Sentence object.

Comment: @Monkey: Well, sure, but what would you do then? If this was a real program, I would think it would be the programmer's responsibility to only call it with values that give meaningful output. The alternative would be for the Sentence class to have a hard-coded list of what classes it will accept, which would be an awfully limiting design decision.

Comment: Further thought: You could, of course, create an Interface with a toSentenceString function or something of the sort, and then only accept inputs of type Interface. That would allow you to control what gets passed in without having to pre-determine the list. But then you couldn't pass in a String or an Integer without wrapping it in something that implemented the interface. Sounds to me like it would be way more trouble than it was worth.