# toString method for varargs constructor

Tags: java, constructor, tostring, variadic-functions

I have a varargs constructor like this :

```
public class Sentence {

   public String[] str;

      public Sentence(Object... text){

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Object o : text) {
          sb.append(o.toString())
          .append(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());

     }

 }
```

The class can can accept various types of data via this constructor (ints, strings, and Sentence objects as well). How do I create a proper toString method for such a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but as the [toString()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method...

> Returns a string representation of the
>   object

...I guess I would store the result of your `sb.toString()` call as a member String variable (say `private String asString`), and return that in a `toString()` method overriding the method in Object:

```
public String toString() {
  return this.asString;
}
```

Comment: it is continuation of this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373419/one-constructor-multiple-arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can't print Sentence in toString because you can get infinite loop if you initialize 2 Senence objects by each other.

So, print all strings and objects and if it's possible some data from Sentence object, or only "1 sentence object" to point that it's also passed as an init param.

Comment: Sorry, how do you get an infinite loop?

Comment: At the moment he won't get it, but if he add `setText(Object...text)` method or something similar then he can expect for the surprise.

Comment: I think @Roman is assuming that `Sentence` would contain a member variable `Object[] objects` that would keep track of which `Object`s are in the `Sentence`, and that `Sentence` would have some sort of `append()` method of its own to allow adding additional `Object`s. In that case, generating a `String` representation inside `toString()` could cause an infinite loop: `Sentence s1 = new Sentence(); Sentence s2 = new Sentence(s1); s1.append(s2);` That would cause an infinite loop. Those assumptions might not be valid though, and I think @Brabster's solution makes more sense overall.